# highlight if the same combination of data appears in another row

Tags: excel, vba

Hi does anyone know how to use excel vba to highlight if the same combination of data appears in another row, within the same group of items (an empty row is used to split them)?

Comment: are you asking how to set the background ([interior color](https://www.thesmallman.com/cell-interior-colour-ith-vba)) of a cell? where are you getting stuck?  Also would the matches always be consecutive rows like your example?

Comment: currently, I'm highlighting the matches manually, so I'm hoping to use excel vba to make it automatic. and no they may not be consecutive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting with a "helper column"

Formula for helper column:
*column can be anyplace on the worksheet, and can be hidden*

```
D2: =A2&B2&C2   *and fill down as far as needed*
```

Then select the three column/ranges to be formatted.
Conditional formatting using a formula:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($D$2:$D$15,$D2)>1,$D2<>"")
```

and set the format for your interior fill

***Edit***
*If the Items within each group are not all the same, as you are now showing in your revised example, then we merely add another helper column: **Index** with the formula:*

`E2: =IF(A2="",ROW(),$E1)`

*And we change the concatenation formula in Column D to:*
`D2: =TEXT($E2,"000")&B2&C2`

[image]

Comment: this works too, never thought of this method, thank you!

Comment: ok, i edited the qtn, is there a way to match if the items are of different names?

Comment: @tngxia just remove them from the concatenation in the helper column. And if you have to keep it within the same blank row separated group, add another column which can serve as an index to separate each group, and include that index in the concatenation.

Comment: @tngxia  See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code it my help!

```
Sub InsBl()
Dim rng, cel As Range
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & LR)
For Each cel In rng
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel.Value) > 1 Then
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Else
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End If
Next cel
End Sub

Dim rng, rng1, cel, cel1 As Range
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("B2:B" & LR)
Set rng1 = Range("C2:C" & LR)
For Each cel In rng
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel.Value) > 1 Then
For Each cel1 In rng1
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, cel.Offset(0, 1).Value) > 1 Then
cel.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
Next cel1
Else
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End If
Next cel
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering but this formula highlights all the items instead. do you know how to let it highlight the same combination (if name and date appear more than once for each item)?

Comment: hi ,you can use the cod above

Comment: this formula highlights all the names and dates instead of the matches now